# I can't install graphene-django in GitHub actions

Tags: django, github, pip, yaml, github-actions

I am building a Django project, and I am using GitHub actions to run `python manage.py test` whenever I push. The problem is that in the project, I am using the `graphene-django` package, which's available to install via `pip install graphene-django`. The problem is that, for some reason, this doesn't seem to work (it outputs an error). I have tried everything:

- `pip install graphene-django`
- `pip install "graphene-django>=2.0"`
- `pip install --user graphene-django`
- `pip install --user "graphene-django>=2.0"`
- `pip3 install graphene-django`
- `pip3 install "graphene-django>=2.0"`
- `pip3 install --user graphene-django`
- `pip3 install --user "graphene-django>=2.0"`

Some of these commands display a different error, but the most common is this:

```
Collecting promise>=2.1 (from graphene-django>=2.0)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/9c/fb5d48abfe5d791cd496e4242ebcf87a4bb2e0c3dcd6e0ae68c11426a528/promise-2.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5vr1pems/promise/
```

Here is my YAML file for the Action (with the last intslling attempt):

```
name: Testing
on: push

jobs:
  test_vote:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Run Django unit tests
      run: |
        pip3 install --user django
        pip3 install --user "graphene-django>=2.0"
        python3 manage.py test
      env:
        # Random key
        SECRET_KEY: '!nj1v)#-y)e21t^u@-6tk+%+#vyzn30dp+)xof4q*y8y&%=h9l'
```

Any help would be really appreciated, since I've been in this for like an hour, when in the [course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbRDkJ4lPdY&feature=emb_title), the teacher took like 5 minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: I am so dumb. I'm sorry, I didn't know that a module meant that. Can you put this as an answer, so I can give you your check? @riQQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the module `setuptools` before installing `graphene-django`.